# SQLite Reset Primary Key Field

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a few tables in SQLite and I am trying to figure out how to reset the auto-incremented database field.

I read that `DELETE FROM tablename` should delete everything and reset the auto-incremement field back to `0`, but when I do this it just deletes the data.  When a new record is inserted the autoincrement picks up where it left off before the delete.

My `ident` field properties are as follows:

- **Field Type**: `integer`
- **Field Flags**: `PRIMARY KEY`, `AUTOINCREMENT`, `UNIQUE`

Does it matter I built the table in SQLite Maestro and I am executing the `DELETE` statement in SQLite Maestro as well?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 314, accepted):

Try this:

```
delete from your_table;    
delete from sqlite_sequence where name='your_table';
```

[SQLite Autoincrement](http://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)

> SQLite keeps track of the largest
>   ROWID that a table has ever held using
>   the special **`SQLITE_SEQUENCE` table**. The
>   `SQLITE_SEQUENCE` table is created and
>   initialized automatically whenever a
>   normal table that contains an
>   AUTOINCREMENT column is created. The
>   content of the SQLITE_SEQUENCE table
>   can be modified using ordinary UPDATE,
>   INSERT, and DELETE statements. But
>   making modifications to this table
>   will likely perturb the AUTOINCREMENT
>   key generation algorithm. Make sure
>   you know what you are doing before you
>   undertake such changes.

Comment: Just a small side note: Table name in where clause is case sensitive

Comment: another way is updating sqlite_sequence table.
update sqlite_sequence set seq = 0 where name='<tablename>'
This will not reset the rowid of sqlite_sequence table.

Comment: @binary, thanks for mentioning an alternative way :) I'd like to note that SQLite reuses "deleted" space, so it doesn't really make much of a difference which solution we'll choose.

Comment: Note that SQLite only creates the sqlite_sequence table when you define an autoincrement column. It doesn't exist before then.

Comment: @ZacharyYates, indeed, but it's already mentioned on the quoted text.

Comment: `no such table sqlite_sequence`  is the error I get when I tried to run that command. What now?

Comment: @dialex, Zachary Yates commented about that and it's also mentioned in my answer.

Comment: can anyone tell how to do this for room ?

Comment: I'm getting: 'SQLiteException: no such column' error on second line of code with this.

Comment: Great, fir me it worked, however I have a question. Why the size of the file is just the same despote we deleted the rows?

Comment: @GSandro_Strongs, the size is the same because SQLite reuse the "deleted" space. There's the [VACUUM command](https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) that rebuilds the database file to take the minimal amount of disk space.

Answer (score 90):

You can reset by update sequence after deleted rows in your-table

```
UPDATE SQLITE_SEQUENCE SET SEQ=0 WHERE NAME='table_name';
```

Comment: can you tell me how to do this for room ?

Comment: what do you mean @Psycho ? I can't understand :)

Comment: actually I was asking how to do this in Room Database..... well the problem is solved for now

Comment: @Psycho can you tell me how you used this using Room database?

Answer (score 6):

As an alternate option, if you have the Sqlite Database Browser and are more inclined to a GUI solution, you can edit the sqlite_sequence table where field name is the name of your table. Double click the cell for the field seq and change the value to 0 in the dialogue box that pops up.

Comment: How does this help for an app in production?

Comment: This answer is very clear, easy to implement and easy to verify that it works

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset every RowId via content provider try this

```
rowCounter=1;
do {            
            rowId = cursor.getInt(0);
            ContentValues values;
            values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Table_Health.COLUMN_ID,
                       rowCounter);
            updateData2DB(context, values, rowId);
            rowCounter++;

        while (cursor.moveToNext());

public static void updateData2DB(Context context, ContentValues values, int rowId) {
    Uri uri;
    uri = Uri.parseContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_HEALTH + "/" + rowId);
    context.getContentResolver().update(uri, values, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with python and you want to delete all records from some table and reset AUTOINCREMENT.

You have this table

```py
tables_connection_db.execute("CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE_DB (id_record INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, value_record real)")
```

So if you had added some records

```py
connection_db=sqlite3.connect("name_file.db")
tables_connection_db=connection_db.cursor()

tables_connection_db.execute("DELETE FROM  MY_TABLE_DB ") # delete records
connection_db.commit()

name_table="MY_TABLE_DB"
tables_connection_db.execute("UPDATE sqlite_sequence SET seq=1 WHERE name=? ",(name_table,))
connection_db.commit()

connection_db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this answer is coming very late, but I am building a .Net Maui app and faced the same issue.  I am using the sqlite-net-pcl nuget and solved this problem by simply dropping the table and creating it again.  The primary key is set back to 1.

```
       database.DropTableAsync<Waypoint>();
       database.CreateTableAsync<Waypoint>().Wait();
```