# Set/Change Rails id auto increment value

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-postgresql

Is there a way for me to set the increment value of id in Rails? Instead of +1, to be +10 (or some other function I specify).

In MySQL there is an option @@auto_increment_increment. Is there a way to set in Rails through ActiveRecord? I am working with both Postgres.

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440401/change-autoincrement-values-in-migration-postgresql-and-sqlite3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Rails 3.x guide on migrations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

There is a example where they hardcode some sql

```
class SomeMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration

    def up
      execute <<-SQL
            ALTER TABLE xxx
      SQL
    end

end
```