# Why can't I reset the row number count in the android DataBase?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, methods

Why can't I reset the row number count in the android DataBase?

```
mDb.delete("SQLITE_SEQUENCE", null, null);
```

Comment: It could matter because sometimes we trying to solve a problem not in a right way in the same time not seeing much straightforward and simple solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// db = SQLiteDatabase
db.rawQuery("delete from your_table", null);
db.rawQuery("delete from sqlite_sequence where name='your_table'", null);
```

For detail, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601697/sqlite-reset-primary-key-field).