# How to start serial value from 1 after deleting all values from table?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using sqlite in my android application.

When i delete all the records from the table then also the next entry is the increment of the last serial.If i delete all records from table,I need to start it from 1 
How to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to reset your AUTO_INCREMENT to 0.

```
DELETE FROM tablename;
DELETE FROM SQLITE_SEQUENCE WHERE name='tablename';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this,

```
delete from sqlite_sequence where name='your_table';
```

Altering SQLITE_SEQUENCE Table is not a good option because it is likely to disturb AUTOINCREMENT Key generation Algorithm. You can see this [`Answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601697/sqlite-reset-primary-key-field).