# (1) near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error when altering table

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to alter an SQLite table defined as follows:

```
    String CREATE_TABLE="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + tab_NAME + " ("
                            + row_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , "
                            + row_NAME + " TEXT, "
                            + row_EMAIL + " TEXT, "
                            + row_WEBSITE + " TEXT, "
                            + row_TELEPHONE1 + " TEXT, "
                            + row_TELEPHONE2 + " TEXT, "
                            + row_TELEPHONE3 + " TEXT, "
                            + row_TELEPHONE4 + " TEXT, "
                            + row_TELEPHONE5 + " TEXT);";
        db_name.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);

        String newTab="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp ("
                + row_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , "
                + row_NAME + " TEXT, "
                + row_EMAIL + " TEXT, "
                + row_WEBSITE + " TEXT, "
                + row_TELEPHONE1 + " TEXT, "
                + row_TELEPHONE2 + " TEXT, "
                + row_TELEPHONE3 + " TEXT, "
                + row_TELEPHONE4 + " TEXT, "
                + row_TELEPHONE5 + " TEXT);";
        db_name.execSQL(newTab);
```

And here is the auto_increment alter statement:

```
    String alter="ALTER TABLE temp AUTO_INCREMENT=1;";
    ourDatabase.execSQL(alter);
```

I got an error saying `(1) near AUTO_INCREMENT: syntax error`

what's wrong?? any help??

Answer (score 26):

In SQLite a column declared `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` will autoincrement by itself. Remove the `AUTOINCREMENT` keyword and then try.

Check the [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1)

Comment: ok, I removed the 
`  String alter="ALTER TABLE temp AUTO_INCREMENT=1;";`
`    ourDatabase.execSQL(alter);`

and it worked well, but I need to reset the auto_increment value to 1, so what to do ?

Comment: Drop the table and re-create it.

Comment: better solution than dropping the table: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1601854/1937033

Answer (score 8):

In `sqlite` setting column as `PRIMARY KEY` is an `AUTOINCREMENT`. So there is no need of specifying explicitly column as `AUTOINCREMENT`. Check the [SQLite FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1).