# How should I initialize my schema via node/npm/knex?

Tags: node.js, npm, knex.js

Every new dev in our project is asked to do:

> To create the database for the first time, run: $ mysql -u root -p <
>   sql/schema.sql

We're using `knex` internally in the project.
How can we use it to create the schema instead or manual mysql commands? How do we hook up npm for that?

Should we do it on `npm install`, or `npm init`? How do we hook up those build targets to `knex`?

Comment: Do you need more than http://knexjs.org/#Migrations provides?

Comment: @Schwern probablly not, need to give it a try. After I code it up, what would be the syntax for a new dev to initialize the db? `knex migrate:latest`? Can I invoke knex from npm, removing the need for people to `npm install --g knex`?

Comment: I don't know any more than the manual, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, a shell script may satisfy your needs:

- create database
- knex migrate latest
- knex run seeds

`npm scripts` is what you want, technically, it just open another shell and run commands in it.