# Why does Django set the pk of all my models to '90'?

Tags: django, sqlite

I'm running Django 1.5 with SQLite, and I have a model called `Assignment`. Whenever I create one, it gets created with the correct `pk` value. But, whenever I try to retrieve any `Assignment` from my database, it is always returned with a pk of `90`. I've been fighting this for an hour, and I have to admit I'm completely confused.

Here's my code, if it's any use.

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        app_label = 'holiday'
        unique_together = ('year', 'employee')

    year = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)
    employee = models.ForeignKey('bsc.Employee', db_index=True)
    days = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
```

This, and a bunch of methods that calculate some values based on models related to this one. Nothing fancy.

I've got to add that this model has had a somewhat rough past - with all my absent-mindedness, I had originally set `year` as the primary key, which quickly failed as soon as I added two `Assignment`s to different employees. Maybe I should look at the DB schema and see if anything's wrong. Thankfully, the app hasn't made it to production yet, but hopefully this can be fixed without a full DB reset.

Comment: You're going to have to show your model definitions.

Comment: Does it only happens with `Assigment` or with all the models as well. Would be useful to see some relevant code or your approaches so far.

Comment: Mmm-hmmm.... I ended up deleting and recreating the tables for my app - manually, since South was also acting up.

Answer (score 1):

If you had created 90 previous records then deleted the rows from your database; your database key index will still be set to what would have been the next primary key number in your database.

The way to resolve this would be to as described in this other stackoverflow post:
[SQLite Reset Primary Key Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601697/sqlite-reset-primary-key-field)