# SQLite: Reset primary key field error

Tags: sqlite

i am working with sqlite and i need to reset the auto increment values, 
I found on StackOverflow:

[SQLite Reset Primary Key Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601697/sqlite-reset-primary-key-field)

but when i do

```
delete from sqlite_sequence where name='my_table';
```

all I got is :

```
Error: no such table: sqlite_sequence
```

Did someone know the problem ? 
I am on an iMac with sqlite3.

Thanks for help !
Have a nice day

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of [autoincrementing columns](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), ones declared as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`, and ones declared as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`.

Columns with `AUTOINCREMENT` have a record in the `sqlite_sequence` table, and can be reset with the above `DELETE` statement.

Plain `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` columns are still autoincrementing, but derive the next value from the largest actual value in the table.
These can be simply reset by deleting all records from the data table itself.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it on my own `sqlite` `DB` and it works fine.

See my [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9b24f/3).

Maybe in your case it could simply be a mistake of your spelling of your table name?
Or a misspelling on keyword **sqlite_sequence** maybe.