# android null pointer while using SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

i am trying to implement an app in which text entered in edittext is saved to the DB and then is displayed in a text field. But the app is crashing when i try to do this and i get a null pointer exception. This is my code

```
   package com.example.dbex;

import java.sql.SQLOutput;
import java.sql.SQLPermission;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="contactsmanager";
    public static final String TABLE_CONTACTS="contacts";
    public static final String KEY_ID="id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME="name";
    public static final String KEY_NUMBER="number";
    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_CONTACTS+"("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+KEY_NAME+" TEXT,"+KEY_NUMBER+" TEXT"+")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_CONTACTS);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addContact(Contacts contacts)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contacts.getname());
        values.put(KEY_NUMBER, contacts.getnumber());
        db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS,null,values);
        db.close();
    }

    public Contacts getContact(int id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c=db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[]{KEY_ID,KEY_NAME,KEY_NUMBER},KEY_ID+" =?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null, null);
        Contacts contacts=null;
        if(c!=null&&c.moveToFirst())
        {
            contacts=new Contacts(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)),c.getString(1),c.getString(2));
        }
        return contacts;
    }

    public void deleteContact(Contacts contacts)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID+" =?", new String[]{String.valueOf(contacts.getID())});
        db.close();
    }


}
```

and the main activity is

```
    package com.example.dbex;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        EditText et1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        EditText et2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final TextView tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        final String _name=et1.getText().toString();
        final String _phone=et2.getText().toString();
        final DBHandler dbh=new DBHandler(getBaseContext());
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dbh.addContact(new Contacts(_name, _phone));
                String contact1=(dbh.getContact(0)).getname();
                tv1.setText(contact1);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

i am getting the null pointer exception in the line

```
                String contact1=(dbh.getContact(0)).getname();
```

where is my mistake?
thanks

Comment: Have you added at least a record to the database?

Comment: yes for that, i am taking input using edittext and adding to DB using button.

Comment: change the table creation `String` to `String CREATE_TABLE_CONTACTS="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_CONTACTS+"("+KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+KEY_NAME+" TEXT,"+KEY_NUMBER+" TEXT"+")";`

Comment: no i am still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are telling you are able to insert the value, I assume your DB creation is correct You have hardcoded the id being queried to 0. You may not be having any value here. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601697/sqlite-reset-primary-key-field) to understand that even when you delete existing rows the auto increment ID could be continuing from the last used value instead of 0. So you could be returning a null value in this part of your code:

```
Contacts contacts=null;
        if(c!=null&&c.moveToFirst())
        {
            contacts=new Contacts(Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)),c.getString(1),c.getString(2));
        }
        return contacts;
```

Comment: no. infact if i use c.getString(1), then i get a null value and the textfield is blank. for c.getstring(0) it simply crashes. Also, i have only defined the delete() function but i havnt used it anywhere so i am not actually deleting any rows.?