# How can I get max value of specific field in Table?

Tags: iphone, ios, sql, objective-c

As my Question says that how can i get maximum value from Table?

In my apps. I have table name **dataset_master**

And table has field name is **dataset_id**, it is add manually as `auto_inc`.

So, First time when no record is inserted in Table and when I insert first record then I add **dataset_id**  is **1.** *(this is only first time)*

And Then after insert next record for **dataset_id** i fire query for get **max** value of **dataset_id** and I insert **dataset_id +1.** *(This is for next record and so on..)*

In my case I use following Query for get maximum **dataset_id**.

```
SELECT MAX(dataset_id) FROM dataset_master where project_id = 1
```

Here in my application I want to get maximum value of field name is **dataset_id** from **dataset_master** table.

This Query properly work when I insert record to **dataset_master** table each time I get proper maximum number of **dataset_id**. But when I delete record in sequins such like *(1 to 5 from 10)* in table and after I insert new record then I got each time last maximum number such like

if my table has 10 record then my **dataset_id** is 1 to 10;
When I delete record such like 1 to 5 then remains 6 to 10 record and also **dataset_id** in Table.
And then after I insert new record then each time I got **10** *(maximum Number)* so each time new record has **dataset_id** is **dataset_id + 1** so **11**.

What is problem I don't know  (may be mistake in Query ?), please give your suggestion.

Comment: So what is the issue, your query is right. just remove where condition.

Comment: no i can not remove where condition because i get datset_id base on project_id so..

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the sequence in the [sqlite_sequence table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601697/sqlite-reset-primary-key-field#comment12300417_1601854). I'd advise you not to worry about this though, as by the time it becomes a problem, this will be the least of your headaches.

Comment: @hd1.. i i found that i can not insert dataset_id more then 10 .. if i insert record then each time i got max dataset_id is 10.. how it is possible ?

Comment: This is why you shouldn't mess with the sqlite_sequence table

Comment: @hd1.. how can i fire Query of  sqlite_sequence table. please give me example because i am new at iOS Development so.. please

Comment: @hd1.. my dataset_id is not auto_incr field ...so also is this query (your) work for me ??? :(

Comment: If you are using auto_incr field, which is stated in your question, this will work for you, if you aren't then all bets are off and, as I implied in my answer, you have a bigger headache.

Comment: @hd1-- ya  i have headache bt how can you know it ?

Comment: I'm just good like that, if your field is not auto_inc, why do you not make it so?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not in your query, but in your insert. Do you force `dataset_id` when inserting new rows?