# How to make django database such that the new objects will get id (last object's id +1) rather than (last deleted object's id+1)?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm writing a django website with a sqlite database, I have a model in my website like this :

```
class Question(models.Model):
question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
def __str__(self):
   return self.question_text
def was_published_recently(self):
   return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

Suppose I create Question object "What's up" and delete it and now create another Question object "HI" then "Hi" will get the id 2 not 1.But I want it to be 1 only.Is this possible?
I m using django 1.8.7 and can't change the version as whole database is written in django 1.8.7.

```
  >> f = Question(question_text="What's up",pub_date=timezone.now())
    >> f.id
       1
    >> f.delete()
    >> g = Question(question_text="Hi",pub_date=timezone.now())
    >> g.id
       2
```

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Comment: Any particular reason to want this behaviour? This would probably cause problems with deletes and foreign keys if cascade is not used

Comment: Actually I have set urls such that i m passing id as one of my parameter so webpage are associated in that way.So somebody if wanted to access the webpage so if he/she hits ip/index/<id> number that page will open but as I have made lot of changes so urls are not in increment form.

Comment: You're opening this up for multipe things to go wrong, if somebody bookmarks a page and that page gets deleted, they'll end up on a different page, this is a security nightmare, specially if the pages are supposed to be access protected, the whole point of that kind of url scheme is that , the urls would be permanent and unique for each resource, if a page or resource is  deleted, the person should get a 404

Comment: You're absolutely right no doubt in that  but in development phase i wanted to do this not after launching it so the problem you stated will not be a problem indeed :)

Comment: In raw SQLite, you would have to [drop the AUTOINCREMENT keyword](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html). I don't know how to do this in Django.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601697/sqlite-reset-primary-key-field

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
class Question(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
```

override save and check the the last available id in the table and incerment by and assign to id.
Though I wouldn't recommend doing this even in dev, seen a lot of code meant for dev only go in prod, just because somebody forgot to remove it