# When I delete all the item's from my query in Django the item id's don't reset

Tags: python, django

I am a complete beginner and I'm creating my first Django webpage following Tech with Tim's tutorials.

I have my first SQLite 3 database entry set up, but I can't seem to figure out why even when I delete every entry from it, when I add a new one it's id is still, for example, 10.

Why aren't the id's resetting back to 0 when I delete everything from the query?

I'm sorry if this question is badly worded or doesn't give enough information, as I said I'm a complete beginner and I'll try to edit my question however nescessary, thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601697/sqlite-reset-primary-key-field

Comment: this answer would be better suited for sqlite as sqlite has sequences similar to postgreSQL

Comment: @iklinac it seems like it would answer my question yes, but I do not understand how to run the command that the top answer suggests

Comment: https://sqlite.org/cli.html

Comment: id field is auto increment so the new items will be added to new id's even if you delete all records

Comment: Primary keys should not be reused anyway (except possibly for a very very few corner cases).

Comment: Thanks everyone, turns out I didn’t need to clear them at all, the issue was elsewhere. Also it makes sense that you wouldn’t want to delete them anyways.